# Rails 3 - How to Render JS after HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How do I render a js.erb file after HTML in a HTML request?

Comment: For what reason? Please spend more time explaining your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a call in a .js or coffee file in the assets/javascripts folder.

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript(location.href);
}
```

You'd probably want to add some conditional logic unless there's a .js.erb file for every url.